# How to resolve ansible issue: Failed to get information on remote file ... Not a directory

Tags: python-3.x, ansible

When I run a playbook `ansible-playbook my-playbook.yml`I am getting this error. But I don't have any file on remote named test.yml.

error

```
TASK [linux-common : copy files to server] *************************************
Saturday 01 August 2020  01:16:19 -0400 (0:00:00.904)       0:00:55.791 ******* 
ok: [172.125.29.147] => (item=/root/downloads/README.md)
fatal: [172.125.29.147]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Failed to get information on remote file (/app/ansible/test.yml): Not a directory"}
```

On the remote host. A directory named 'app' has been created but no files is in it.

try-playbook.yml

```
 ---
 - hosts: flaskbox_dev
 
   remote_user: root
   roles:
     - linux-common
```

[playbook roles]linux-common/tasks/main.yml

```
- name: copy files to server
  copy: 
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: /app
  loop:
    - /root/odesi_downloads/README.md
    - ./ansible
    - ./tasks.todo
    - ./conf.d
    - ./cronjobs
    - ./dockerfiles
    - ./dotfiles
    - ./flaskapp
    - ./requirements
    - ./screenshots
    - ./Makefile
    - ./README.md
    - ./run.py
    - ./.coveragerc
    - ./inventory
    - ./pytest.ini
    - ./tests
    - ./app_test.py
  register: copy_output
- debug: var=copy_output
```

I have been using my playbook for 2 weeks and that is the first time that I have that issue. I upgraded ansible to 2.9.11 and still have the same issue.

Comment: I do not know `ansible`, but this page seems to be of interest: https://coderwall.com/p/8yfuva/how-to-develop-ansible-roles-w-unit-test-and-ci m it has a line which says: `Create tests directory and prepare a ansible playbook named test.yml as follows`

Comment: I suspect you created an `/app/ansible` **file** during your tests, which is on the way of copying the entire **directory**. If this is the case, simply remove it and it should fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks @Luuk. The tests folder is related with the flask app. I don't have a tests.yml in my current directory. I don't know why ansible pointed to that file.

Comment: Hi @Zeitounator thanks maybe ansible created a file 'ansible' instead moving the folder 'ansible'. I am not quite sure what went wrong. I have been running this test for two weeks and that's the first time that this issue occured

Answer (score 1):

I had to create the folder `/app` before copying my file

```
 - name: Create Folder /app if not exist
   file:
     path: /app
     mode: 0755
     state: directory

- name: copy files to server
  copy: 
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: /app
  loop:
    - /root/odesi_downloads/README.md
    - ./ansible
    - ./tasks.todo
    - ./conf.d
    - ./cronjobs
    - ./dockerfiles
    - ./dotfiles
    - ./flaskapp
    - ./requirements
    - ./screenshots
    - ./Makefile
    - ./README.md
    - ./run.py
    - ./.coveragerc
    - ./inventory
    - ./pytest.ini
    - ./tests
    - ./app_test.py
  register: copy_output
- debug: var=copy_output
```